# How to know whether a piece of JS is executed in an ES Module or a regular script?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to know whether a piece of JavaScript is executed in an ES module or a simple script.

This is what I tried so far:

```js
function isEsm1() {
  try {
    // Script gives a syntax error during parsing when script is not an esm
    return Boolean(import.meta.url); 
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

function isEsm2() {
  // will always return false, because `eval` always seems to be executed in regular script context
  try {
    return eval('Boolean(import.meta.url)'); 
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}


function isEsm3() {
  // Of course doesn't work, but had to try 
  return 'meta' in import; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? In general you shouldn't need this, you would always know how your code is executed.

Comment: @Bergi it's a very, very, very edge case: mutation testing. See https://github.com/stryker-mutator/stryker-js/issues/2922#issuecomment-893442035 if you want to know the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the discussion in John Gorter's answer, I think we've found a way.

`console.log('In module: ' + (this === undefined));`

It's as simple as that. Inside a module (and only inside a module (I hope)), `this` will be `undefined`. I found it in the v8 documentation here: https://v8.dev/features/modules#intro

Comment: Note that `this` is also `undefined` in functions in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#securing_javascript). This is also possible outside of modules. https://jsfiddle.net/30Loyz5f/

Comment: Note that this won't work when an `import` is being resolved by Webpack (and likely other bundlers as well).

Answer (score 0):

Is the regular script executed in the browser or in another context?

In a browser, how about:

```js
var anyvar = {};
var inModule = anyvar === window.anyvar;
```

If you're in a module, you are not declaring anything on the window...

In NodeJS you could do something similar with global or this:

```js
let inModule = this === module.exports..
```

Did not try it yet.. but should work I guess...

After testing, just the check for `this === undefined` is enough to test if you're executing in or out of a module..

Inside a module, this is undefined (as per spec). In global scope this points to global this, which is the window object in the case of a browser context...

Comment: Perhaps I answered a little too fast here.. could you provide a little more context? Do you want to determine inside global functions if they are called from within module?

Comment: Thanks John! 

I would like it to work in all contexts: browser, nodejs, deno, etc. I want to inject this piece of code on the top of each JS file to determine whether or not it was loaded as an ESM at runtime and store that in a global variable. Like code coverage instrumentation. I think it might be useful for improving mutation testing in StrykerJS.

Comment: You're trick with `var anyvar = {}; var inModule = anyvar === window.anyvar` would only work in a script that is loaded without a module loader like commonjs or requirejs. And for nodejs `let inModule = this === module.exports..` won't work. `this` points to `globalThis` in nodejs.

Comment: My assumption was that you used native/vanilla es 6 modules in browser contexts (script type=module). For those the first trick would work.  GlobalThis is not the same as module.exports. In my understanding when you require a module in NodeJS, inside the module this is a reference to module.exports, not globalThis..    anyways, I guess there is no one simple way to catch all your usecases and I don't know enough about the external module loaders like commons or requirejs..

Comment: Just tested it. This in a NodeJS module is referring to module.exports and not globalThis. GlobalThis in NodeJS is referring to global. The global context of NodeJS. So the latter should work for NodeJS modules as well..

Comment: I even think that the first trick would work in a commonjs context as well, since it also uses local scope for it's modules. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Didn't know `this` referred to `module.exports`, thanks for pointing that out to me. Yet `var anyvar = {}; var inModule = anyvar === window.anyvar` works as I expected, this is false in both mjs and cjs. Would also be false in webpack bundled code and the like. Also false in the browser with `<script type="module">`, as expected.

I would prefer any solution to detect native ESM, instead of detecting every other module loader / script variant. I wouldn't want to put it in if I would run the risk of not supporting a more obscure bundler ‍♀️

Comment: actually my findings are different:


```<script>
        var b = {};
        console.log("normal script", b == window.b);
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        var a = {};
        console.log("in module", a == window.a);
    </script>```

outputs:

normal script true
 in module false

Only tested it in browser (chrome), not the module loaders, so it probably is not a complete answer to your question, perhaps only some interesting findings... :-)

Comment: Here is a JsFiddle that shows what I meant: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw0tn7rd/

Comment: Here is another variant for browsers using something similar.. again, let me know if I am understanding you correctly.... However, I did notice something strange: when using insideModule.call(this) in the next fiddle, if this is undefined (which is the case in the module) then it reverts back to the global window object, did not know that :-)

Here is the other example: https://jsfiddle.net/jys5au6n/

Comment: Hmm interesting. This simple check seems to be enough (in the root of the file):

`console.log('In module: ' + (this === undefined));` I thought the JS inside a module was simply `strict` mode, but apparently `this` also works differently. I'm going to look for the exact spec.

Comment: Here it is: https://v8.dev/features/modules#intro

> the `this` within modules does not refer to the global `this`, and instead is `undefined`.

Comment: If you document it in a new answer, or update your answer, I will mark it as the correct answer, so you get some nice shiny internet credits!

Comment: Credits are not my goal. Understanding and sharing is.  But I will update the answer for others to find...